# help on building the robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to built a robot that is able to do avoid obstracles using the ultra sonic sensor and the robot is controlled by touch screen, i like to implement wall following modes and door passing modes using the sensor. for this
do ros provide code to implement control of the robot??
but i found some codes in java from the book "linux robotics" by d.newman but that book use RTLinux os how to re use those code in ros??
since iam planning to use ping sensor how i can interface it to pc where ros is running?? usb ? how?
im intrested in adding some navigation algorithm to make the robot autonomous or semi autonomous atleast?? i gone through d* and polar mapping algorithm?? but dont know how to implement it using ros??
please give some links,books, circuit links

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52829/help-on-building-the-robot/) by [vikirobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/3978/vikirobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-01-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I think that ROS is exactly what you are looking for, but it will take you a while to implement all that you mentioned. Basically mostly of what you are planning to use will be implemented in ros to one of the robots I mention below, but you will be able to adapt the code.

Looking at your questions, you should start implementing some tutorials to understand how ros works [ROS wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/).

Here I attach some information that can be useful to you (you are not explaining what kind of robot are you going to build, so take a look and decide what ever you want to use).

Robots using ros: [Robots](http://ros.org/wiki/Robots)

Navigation stack (mostly implemented to PR2 robot): [Navigation stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation)

I strongly recommend you to go step by step (this will help you to post more specific questions).

I hope this will help you, and good luck.

Àngel.

---

Originally posted by [Àngel - IRI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1795/%C3%A0ngel---iri/) with karma: 74 on 2013-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0